# Require reputation for answer, not for comment

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

Stack Overflow requires 50 reputation for commenting and no rep for answering. But answering is for experts and commenting is for everyone. Anyone may want to say many things by commenting. Also they are able to answer by commenting. But they aren't able to say by answering. So, require rep for answering instead of commenting.

Comment: How is one supposed to get started?

Comment: As to the comment without rep, what a lovely idea for spammers, let's have comment spam on every post.

Comment: FEATURE REQUEST ENLARGEMENT PILLS, ONLY $49.95 AT SuckersLogInWithYourCard.com!

Comment: Did you search this site regarding previous questions asking to lower the rep requirements for commenting? Please do so in the future before asking things that would be disastrous for this site.

Comment: Just like on your other Q, shakil... you have massive misunderstandings about this site. Comments are second class citizens, of so little importance the site shouldn't be affected too much if we remove  them.  Anyway, without rep from answers, how does one get started? Only edits and questions? Seems.... harder than it is now. You were asking on Meta how to get rep. Removing the most straightforward way to get rep will make this site even harder to use.

Comment: @AAShakil: "*But answering is for experts and commenting is for everyone.*" No. Answers are for people who know the answer. Commenting is for people who want to answer but cannot, because the question is unclear and they need clarification. If you're not in a position to provide useful information (ie: answers), you don't need to be making comments.

Comment: Another point that hasn't been mentioned yet is that bad question and answer posts can be removed by the community with flags and votes but removing comments can only be done by diamond moderators in most cases. There has to be more upfront prevention of spam in comments because only a few people can delete them.

Answer (score 19):

> Anyone may want to say many things by commenting.

All the more reason why we shouldn't *allow* just anyone to say anything they want. That would be disastrous.

You are not obligated to answer questions if you don't feel that you are knowledgeable enough to do so. You can earn rep by asking good questions, too.

Answer (score 18):

Answers are the **single most important feature** this site has to offer.

Having answers to questions is what brings people to Stack Overflow in the first place, it is the reason this site is successful. We'll not raise the bar for people to provide answers.

As you state:

> But answering is for experts

Exactly, and if the one expert with the answer to a difficult question comes to the site, and has no reputation points, **we will not stand in their way to provide the answer**.

Answers also cause a question to be bumped in the 'active' questions listings, so are quickly seen by others that look out for new material being posted. Answers from new accounts are also subject to review, so abuse is usually spotted quickly.

Comments, on the other hand, only are there to help improve the quality of questions and answers, not for any other reason. Comments are therefore not searchable and don't bump up questions on question listings, making it a little harder to spot abuse early. So we want to give that privilege only to people that understand the goals of the site, and the role comments play in that, a little better. That's why comments have a minimum reputation requirement, and answers do not.

This is not something we will change.

Answer (score 7):

> So, require rep for answering

I think this is a terrible idea. What if the only person who knows the answer to the question doesn't have the rep to answer? Should OP and everyone else be prevented from solving their problem, just because somebody else hasn't been upvoted yet?

The same is true for similar proposals to require reputation for asking. I know that if I was prevented to ask my questions when I was starting programming, I would not have any motivation to answer questions years later.

Regarding the reputation requirement for commenting, I would agree that it can be problematic sometimes, but comments are not considered as essential as questions and answers in a Q/A site. But do realize that removing this restriction would necessitate new moderation tools and resources, as @BoltClock mentions. It also adds a gamification aspect, which could (in
theory) motivate some people to participate more.